# Wowza statistics processing

Tags: logging, streaming, wowza, visitor-statistic

I've been looking for a free app for processing Wowza logs, and I've found only these:

- [CegaraWowStats](http://cegarawowstats.blogspot.cz/) - looks good, the problem is that the sources were hosted only at megaupload, and the admin looks like he's not maintaning the site anymore
- [awstats mod for process wowza stats](http://www.wmconsulting.info/awstats-mod-for-process-wowza-stats/)

Do you know some others?

Answer (score 1):

You could use this solution from Ian Beyer if you like customization:
http://blog.ianbeyer.com/code/backend/wowza-metrics-perl/

When our team was reviewing Wowza reporting solutions, we found the same old problem of free SW - it gives basic functionality but when it comes to features extension or support, there's no way to do it good. That's why we've built our own [Wowza control panel](https://wmspanel.com/) :)

Answer (score 1):

[Wowza Measure](http://wowzatoolbox.com/measure) allows you to capture connection counts directly into your database using your own SQL queries, which is quite flexible. This might make processing of the logs unnecessary, as you can insert data into your tables as you go and you can always query these tables. Here is a tutorial on [logging player numbers](http://wowzatoolbox.com/logging-player-counts-to-db).

Answer (score 0):

Try this control panel [www.owiza.com](http://www.owiza.com).

It looks like the website is still ongoing but it functions well and the sign up is for free; I recommend you to try it.